# How to hide textfield with label?

Tags: extjs

I have textfield:

```
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'LBL_EMAIL',
                anchor: '100%',
                listeners: {
                    'render': function(p) {
                        // check certain conditions
                        this.hide()
                    }
                },
            },
```

"hide()" only hides textbox (without label) and I want hide whole row (textbox and label).
Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, i'm try to make it in listeners because i want show/hide it after some checks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution, I have to configure the FormLayout with:

```
trackLabels: true
```

Answer (score 2):

Maciej's answer didn't work more me.  Putting this in Ext's defaults did:

`Ext.layout.FormLayout.prototype.trackLabels = true;`

Comment: Put "trackLabels" in "layoutConfig" as: layoutConfig: {
      trackLabels: true
     }

Answer (score 2):

I had to do following to make it work.

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    anchor: '100%',
    listeners: {
        'render': function(p) {
            // hide label
            Ext.getCmp('cluster_name').getEl().up('.x-form-item').setDisplayed(false);
        }
    },
},
```

Comment: Works! Also you can use *this* instead of  *Ext.getCmp('cluster_name')*

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.getCmp('id of textfield').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
yourElement.container.up('div.x-form-item').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sencha Architect (v4.3.0.108 and extJS v7.4.0.45), you can add a Render Event Binding and then inside this write:

`component.hide();`

This will hide the field and its label.

But thanks for your answers. They pointed me in the right direction.